# SelectionChange not passing on codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Scenario: User clicks on edit icon, dialog box appears. If clicked yes (or Ok, a positive response), a function starts working behind.

and of course it is not working and I can't understand why.

Icon and the dialog box. Notice the action tag.

```
<div style="float:left; padding-top:10px; margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px;">
<div class "btnbeyan" value="{Index}"  action ="cancel"  style="float:left; cursor: pointer; padding-top:10px; margin-right:5px; margin-left:5px;">
<img src="../../../img/Edit_Icon.png" OnClick=" if(!confirm('Beyanı değiştirmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?')) return false;" style ="cursor: pointer;" />
</div>
<img src="../../../img/imgTrue.png"/>
</div>
```

Selection change part:

```
<SelectionChange OnEvent="dvBeyanlar_SelectionChange" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<ExtraParams>
<ext:Parameter Name="id" Value="selections[0].getAttribute('value')" Mode="Raw">
</ext:Parameter>
<ext:Parameter Name="action" Value="selections[0].getAttribute('action')" Mode="Raw">
</ext:Parameter>
</ExtraParams>
<EventMask ShowMask="True" Target="This" />
</SelectionChange>
```

C# codebehind

```
protected void dvBeyanlar_SelectionChange(object sender, Ext.Net.DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        int Index = Convert.ToInt32(e.ExtraParams["id"]);
        if (e.ExtraParams["action"] == "del")
        {
            DelBeyan(Index);
        }
        else if (e.ExtraParams["action"] == "cancel")
        {
            TescilDuzeltme(Index);
        }
        else EditBeyan(Index);
    }
```

and lastly, TescilDuzeltme ()

```
public void TescilDuzeltme(int BeyanIndex)
    {
        //a Stored Procedure works
        //Response.Redirect();
    }
```

Dialog box works fine but when I click yes in debug mode,  I see nothing going on in dvBeyanlar_SelectionChange, what am I missing?

Edit: Most of the code was written by another employee, I'm just making some modifications on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I forgot a "=" in class "btnbeyan"..

it should be as "class="btnbeyan"

Not sure if I should delete the question or leave it in case someone makes same absent-mindedness in future.